# Migrate SilverStripe website from one server to another

Tags: silverstripe

I migrated a SilverStripe website from one server to another. To do that I took the following steps:

1. Transferred a backup of the files from the old server and to the new server.
2. Dumped the old Database and imported it to the new server.
3. Updated _conn.php to connect to the new database.

Now when I hit the URL in a browser it is giving a 500 error. I didn't update the DNS for new server, instead I point to new server from my local system via hosts file. If I hit mywebsite.com/robots.txt, it is showing the robots.txt but not showing other pages.

Answer (score 1):

500 error means server error which means something in apache(?), php or other logs.  Ensure debug mode is on for SilverStripe to get the most information.

If all else fails start with checking your `.htaccess` is fine and redirecting and use with debug [die] statements progressively.

Ideally use the [silverstripe-installer](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer) to debug any server issues and install a clean install, then you can copy the site over when you know it is working.